# Infix to postfix for negative numbers

Tags: infix-notation, postfix-mta, infix-operator

How do I convert negative numbers from infix to postfix ?

Suppose I have a expression

a = - b - (-c-d)

In some places I read that you can parathesize the negative numbers like

a = (-b) - (-c-d)

But here if I do that, I will get a term like "ab-" at the beginning of the postfix expression which means a-b and is incorrect.

How do I convert this ?

Comment: Why is this tagged `c`?

Comment: What postfix notation are you using?

Comment: I assume you are storing the values of the variables. Try storing the numbers as negative but show the operation in the character array as positive (+)

Comment: Does (-c-d) mean ((-c) - d) in which case I do not understand the question or does it mean (-c x d), in which case this question has no business being tagged [C] and is a maths question rather then a programming question.

Comment: _"if I do that, I will get a term like "ab-..."_ eh!?  Where the the a come from?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In infix notation, you must distinguish between the binary subtraction operator **sub** and the unary negation operator **neg**. Both are represented by a minus sign, but the context tells you which is which.

You've got a *negation*, when the minus as at the beginning of the expression, or after an opening parenthesis or after a binary operator:

− (*x* + *y*)   →   *x* *y* **add** **neg**
    4 × − *x*   →   4 *x* **neg** **mult**
    2 × (− *x* + y)   →   2 *x* **neg** *y* **add** **mult**

You've got a *subtraction* when the minus is after a closing parenthesis or after a symbol, i.e. after a variable or number:

1 − *x*   →   1 *x* **sub**
    (4 ∗ *x*) − *1*   →   4 *x* **mult** 1 **sub**

Take care that the unary operator **neg** just takes one argument off the stack. If you want to stick with binary operators, you can push a zero before the second operand and use binary **sub**:

− (*x* + *y*)   →   0 *x* *y* **add** **sub**
    4 *x* **neg** **mult**   →  4 0 *x* **sub** **mult**
    2 *x* **neg** *y* **add** **mult**   →   2 0 *x* **sub** *y* **add** **mult**

Finally, you can apply a similar logic to unary plus, which you can just ignore:

+ *x*   →   *x*
    + (*x* + *y*)   →   *x* *y* **add**